# Open source MPG to FLV Converter?

Tags: c#, .net, actionscript-3, open-source

Anyone know or use an open source MPG to FLV converter that I would be able to use programatically?  Preferably .NET .  If you know any .NET commercial ones also then I would be grateful of those links too.

Cheers,

Andrew

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can do this with FFMPEG.

There is a .NET wrapper for it [here](http://ffmpegdotnet.codeplex.com/).

**EDIT:**

It looks like the .NET wrapper on codeplex isn't fully complete.  You might want to take a look at the [InnerTube](http://www.c4fbook.com/innertube) project on the coding4fun site as it downloads flv files and converts them to wmv.  The source code for that might point you in the right direction.